# WinError2 when renaming a file

Tags: python, rename, python-zipfile

This code extracts pictures from a .xlsx file, copy them three times and renames them.
It all works fine when I extract them to the same directory where the file and the code are, but if I try to extract it to a different directory (\renamedPix) I get:

```py
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Impossible to find the specified file: 'image1.jpeg' -> 'newPicone0.jpeg'
```

What I'm doing wrong?
(Here below is an updated version: I tried using os.mkdir() but I get the same error)>

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
import re
import os
import shutil

file_name= "fote.xlsx"
directory= "renamedPix"
parent_dir = "C:\\Users\\divel\\Desktop"
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)
os.mkdir(path)

with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zipObj:
     counter = 0
     
     for file in zipObj.infolist():
         name = file.filename
         match = re.findall("jpeg$", name)
         
         if match:
            filename = os.path.basename(file.filename)
            
            for i in range(3):
                source = zipObj.open(file)
                target = open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb')
                
                with source, target :
                    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
                pic_names = ['one', 'two', 'three']
                new_name = 'newPic'+pic_names[i]+str(counter)+'.jpeg'
                os.rename(filename, new_name)
            counter += 1
```

Comment: Why did you place `file_name` inside `zip()` and `list()` method?

Comment: Do you understand that `''.join(list(file.filename))` is absolutely pointless?  So is `list(zip(file_name))`, but you don't ever use `lista`.  Are you sure that `Desktop/renamedPix` exists?  Perhaps you should check for that and do `os.mkdir`.

Comment: `lista = list(zip(file_name))` is something I tried and forgot altogether. I'm not sure what I was thinking. `Desktop/renamedPix` did exist. I'm trying to make this work now: `directory= "renamedPix"
parent_dir = "C:\\Users\\divel\\Desktop"
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)
os.mkdir(path)` and then extract the file this way: `target = open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb')
                with source, target :
                    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)` I get the same error though.

Comment: At which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Have you tried providing `os.rename` full source and destination paths?

Comment: Thank you for getting in touch. I solved the problem last year but as of now I can't exactly remember how.